# What should I understand by "try outlook"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs, proper-nouns, capitalization, abbreviations

I received an email from my boss telling the sentence:  "Try outlook resources inc DBA Company Name". I am not sure what it means, what I asked him was to confirm a number account that he gave me wrong.

Comment: Outlook the email client? (which also includes contact details which might include the information you seek).

Comment: Thanks. My boss confirm, "outlook resources inc" is just the account name. I am not sure what DBA means (is not Database administrator)

Comment: Was "outlook resources inc" written just like that in the email? That is, no capital letters, and no comma before _inc_?

Comment: @J.R. - yeah, I agree with your comment - if it was written like that its not exactly that clear.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, following your comments about "outlook resources inc" being the name of the company, clears this up a little.  In the USA this would more conventionally be written "Outlook Resources, Inc" - capitalizing the first letter of each word, and a comma between the name and the fact that it is "Incorporated".  The fact that it was not written like this made it harder for me to understand.

DBA as you suspected, does not mean Database Administrator, it means "Doing Business As". As I'm sure you know, the official company name and its "brand name" may be very different.

So this sentence means ... try this company name, giving you both the official legal name, as well as the name that it trades under and is generally better known by.